# Kotlin compilation errors, unresolved reference: rotation and unresolved reference: getSize

Tags: android, kotlin

I didn't have to touch one of my Android projects for over a year, but now I have to make some modifications. Last time everything worked fine, but now I installed new Android Studio version, and upgraded the Android SDK and build tools and everything AS told me to.

There seems to be a problem I can't get rid of, I get strange Kotlin compilation errors. I have a Kotlin "class" that has an ImageView field:

```
private var iv_arrow : ImageView? = null
```

I want to set the rotation field:

```
iv_arrow?.rotation = 0f
```

This produces the following compilation error in the output:

> e: C:\Android\somedir\somefile.kt:
>   (259, 31): Unresolved reference: rotation

In the IDE everything seems to be fine:

[Screenshot of IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qK80c.png)

The same error is produced when calling android.view.Display.getSize.

If I remove these calls from the code, the project is built successfully.

I have the following settings in my project's build.gradle file:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

And the module's build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
```

Does anyone have the idea why the compilation error is produced?

Additional information: upgrading the Kotlin version to 1.3.0 does not seem to help.

**EDIT:**

The view is defined in xml and got by the following code:

```
iv_arrow = rootView?.findViewById(R.id.prod_details_iv_right_arrow) as? ImageView
```

Strangely, other calls to this same instance of iv_view do not produce compilation errors, for example these are fine by the compiler:

```
iv_arrow?.clearAnimation()
iv_arrow?.startAnimation(rotate)
```

Comment: iv_arrow is a view in your xml or an ImageView object?
if its a view then kindly check with your imports of following activity or fragment weather it has imported the same xml where iv_arrow exists or not!

Comment: @Akash Dubey: I edited the post to add the information. I think the problem is not with resolving the view.